# Pass update_all_types on ElasticSearch Put Mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

We are upgrading to ElasticSearch 2.0 and have come across an issue with our mappings in Nest 1.7.0 : we have two types that share a field (with the same format):

```
"@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "epoch_millis||dateOptionalTime"
          }
```

When we try to add a mapping on startup for one of the affected types (we are currently `PUT`ing the mappings every time), we get this error back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [{
      "type": "merge_mapping_exception",
      "reason": "Merge failed with failures {[mapper [@timestamp] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [format] across all types.]}"
    }],
    "type": "merge_mapping_exception",
    "reason": "Merge failed with failures {[mapper [@timestamp] is used by multiple types. Set update_all_types to true to update [format] across all types.]}"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

We are using a code based mapping described [here](https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/put-mapping.html), but I do not see a way of hanging a query string off of this method without resorting to the `Raw` property of our client using something like this:

`_client.Raw.IndicesPutMapping("ourindex", "ourtype", PutMappingDescriptorObj, parameters => parameters.AddQueryString("update_all_types", null));`

I've browsed the [2.0 branch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/2.0) of Nest, but have not found any references to this update_all_types query string parameter for these mapping calls.

Assuming that `IndicesPutMapping()` call could be made to work, is that our only option at this point? I am starting to wonder if we should instead only conditionally add these mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we were able to find another way: when we were creating our mapping we were not explicitly providing a format for our `@timestamp` field, and with 2.0 that seemingly caused the system to treat it as a change, hence our issue. We were able to get past this by, in our mapping logic, pin on the existing format for these date fields like this:

```
// formatted strangely to make the addition more obvious
_client.Map<OurType>(m =>
    m.Properties(ps => ps
        .Date(d => d.Name(es => es.Date) // es is a reference to an instance of OurType, and Date is the name of the field being mapped to @timestamp
                    .Format("epoch_millis||dateOptionalTime") // this is what fixed it
             )
        //other props
    )
    //other stuff
);
```